# Returning value from if else in ERLANG

Tags: erlang

```
parse(Tuples,Str,Block) ->
  if Block =:= 1 ->
        Str1=string:substr(Str,1,1),
        Str2=string:substr(Str,2,4),
        Tuple2=Tuples++[{a,Str1},{b,Str2}];
     Block =:= 2 ->
        Str3=string:substr(Str,1,1),
        Str4=string:substr(Str,2,3),
        Tuple2=Tuples++[{c,Str3},{d,Str4};
     true-> ok
  end.
```

I am a newbie to erlang. Is there a way to return the tuple2 value from this function? if not what is the work around? 
when i try to return Tuple2 after end it gives
variable 'Tuple2' unsafe in 'if'.
and when i use it above 'if' the Tuple2 cannot be altered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `Tuple` is being 'returned' in the first two cases. Remember, in Erlang the last expression is always used as the return value. The reason you get the warning is that `Tuple2` is not given a value in all branches. For example, what if `Block` was 3? `Tuple2` would not be defined.

Let's rewrite this in a more idiomatic way to better see what is returned:

```
parse(Tuples,Str,Block) ->
  case Block of
    1 ->   
      Str1=string:substr(Str,1,1),
      Str2=string:substr(Str,2,4),
      Tuple2=Tuples++[{a,Str1},{b,Str2}];
    2 ->
      Str3=string:substr(Str,1,1),
      Str4=string:substr(Str,2,3),
      Tuple2=Tuples++[{c,Str3},{d,Str4};
    _ ->
      ok
  end.
```

The last expression in each branch of the case expression will be 'returned'.
If you don't see this, consider the following:

```
1> case 1 of
1>   1 -> ok;
1>   2 -> nok
1> end.
ok
```

`ok` is 'returned' from that case expresion (the case expression evaluates to `ok`).

Let's rewrite the original code to be even more idiomatic:

```
parse(Tuples, Str, 1) ->
  Str1=string:substr(Str,1,1),
  Str2=string:substr(Str,2,4),
  Tuple2=Tuples++[{a,Str1},{b,Str2}];
parse(Tuples, Str, 2) ->
  Str3=string:substr(Str,1,1),
  Str4=string:substr(Str,2,3),
  Tuple2=Tuples++[{c,Str3},{d,Str4};
parse(_, _, _) ->
  ok.
```